# Firebase Authentication - How to delete user account using their emails?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can I delete not authenticated user's account? The docs offers such a way:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
user.delete()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Is this the only way to delete account?

Comment: please look into ans  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114689/how-to-delete-a-firebase-user-from-android-app/38114865#38114865

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade so, there is no way to do any operations with account if the user is not signed in?

Comment: IF you want to delete then user must have to signed in.

Comment: or you can delete the user manually using the firebase console

Comment: this question is an old one but should give you some toughts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23383826/remove-a-user-from-firebase

Comment: *firebaser here* We are working on making admin functionality available for Firebase Authentication in the server SDKs. Until that is released (no ballparks yet), the only way to delete a user is to sign them in or through the console.